# ImportError: No module named 'myapp' when starting flask with uwsgi

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi

When I load my Flask app on my nginx/ubuntu server using uwsgi, I get this trace:

```
ImportError: No module named 'myapp'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
*** no app loaded. going in full dynamic mode ***
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
```

my structure is like so:

```
myapp/
     /__init__.py
     /project.ini
     /wsgi.py
```

**wsgi.py**

```
from myapp import app 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**project.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
module = wsgi:app
master = true
processes = 5

socket = myapp.sock
chmod-socket = 660
vacuum = true
logto = /var/www/myapp/logs/%n.log
die-on-term = true
```

I have tried adding `callable = app` in my ini file.  I have tried aliasing app as application in wsgi.py.

I see so many questions on S.O. on this topic and nothing is helping.  Any thoughts?

**EDIT**:

Same result as above.

**EDIT2:**

**/etc/systemmd/system/myapp.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=uWSGI instance to serve myapp
After=network.target

[Service]
User=egr  
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/myapp
Environment="PATH=/var/www/myapp/klenv/bin"
ExecStart=/var/www/myapp/klenv/bin/uwsgi --ini project.ini

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: What is your working directory? Try adding `chdir=<parent_directory_to_myapp>` into your `ini` file.

Comment: Yes, nothing wrong with your `ini` but just with your working directory.

Comment: @Selcuk  I added my service config as well.  I had a "workingdirectory" setting there.  Does this work as well?  or need in the ini too (or instead of)?

Comment: @Sraw  See the comment above.  I have edited my question to include the service file where I _thought_ I set this.

Comment: Thanks guys, your answer got me on the right path. See answer below.

Comment: @KickingLettuce Glad to be of help. You can accept your own answer too.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments above, I was led on the right track.

What I needed was a folder structure like this:

```
myapp/
     /wsgi.py 
     myapp/
         /__init.py__
```

I realized my parent directory was wrong (well, it was fine, but my app could not be seen inside it).  I needed one more layer of folders between what I set as the parent directory and my module with **init** declaring the app.